# Internal server error while connecting to my database online

Tags: php, mysql, internal-server-error

I'm using the following code to connect to a database that I have setup on godaddy.com. But when I try to run the script I get "Internal Server Error".

```
<?php
$db_conx = mysqli_connnect('MY_WEBSITE.secureserver.net', 'MY_USERNAME', 
 'MY_PASSWORD', 'DATABASE_NAME');

 // Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "cannot connect to database";
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} 
else {
     echo "Successful database connection, happy coding!!!";
}
?>
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you provide the output of var_dump(mysqli_connect_error());

Comment: You're not going to be able to see the var dump if the page isn't rendering. Make sure you are showing any errors, or check the server logs for more details. The code looks okay.

Comment: what I see is 
"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log"

Comment: So have you looked at the server error log?

Comment: @BillKarwin see information about computer and browser followed by the following:
cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
evocature.com 404 0 2 1326 174 171

Comment: I figured it out. I had the wrong connection string. it should have been $con instead of $db_conx